# Не удается пропарсить сайт

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Использую библиотеку HtmlAgilityPack для парсинга сайта. На одном сайте данные выводятся сразу, на другом сайте возникает ошибка соединения (xpath выражения разные). Думаю, что на сайте стоит защита от ботов и не удается пропарсить сайт. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно узнать, стоит ли на сайте защита от ботов.

P.S. Можно ускорить процесс парсинга сайта? Открыв карточку товара, необходимо пропарсить страницу и получить наименование товара. На странице только один товар. Данный процесс занимает около 8 секунд.

Comment: Ошибка соединения скорее всего говорит о проблеме комуникации между вашей программой и сайтом. HTML парсинг тут не при чем.

Comment: `Данный процесс занимает около 8 секунд.` разбейте процесс на части (1) днс поиск и подключение к сайту 2)  Загрузка данных с сайта 3) поиск по загруженным данным) - и определите, что конкретно у вас медленно рабтает. 4

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста проблемный код в вопросе.